# How to include a list of Vector2 as a property in XML for the XNA framework

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, xna

I have a class which i want to use for importing data into a game that i'm creating with XNA. The basis of it is, i've looked around and tried a few things but i can't get this to compile properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="MyGameData.LevelXMLData">
  <LevelID>1</LevelID>
  <Path>
    <Item>1379 541</Item>
    <Item>1370 445</Item>
    <Item>1340 348</Item>
    <Item>1294 253</Item>
    <Item>1217 148</Item>
    <Item>1139 106</Item>
    <Item>1077 148</Item>
    <Item>1046 201</Item>
    <Item>1004 479</Item>
    <Item>999 633</Item>
    <Item>961 816</Item>
    <Item>917 918</Item>
    <Item>850 964</Item>
    <Item>824 939</Item>
    <Item>770 837</Item>
    <Item>738 673</Item>
    <Item>725 526</Item>
    <Item>549 520</Item>
  </Path>
  <WaveIDs>
    <Item>Wave1</Item>
    <Item>Wave2</Item>
    <Item>Wave3</Item>
  </WaveIDs>
  <WaveInterval>120000</WaveInterval>
  <TowerBuildSpots>
    <Item>1277 417 50 50</Item>
    <Item>1094 232 50 50</Item>
    <Item>956 207 50 50</Item>
    <Item>931 326 50 50</Item>
    <Item>1069 442 50 50</Item>
    <Item>906 566 50 50</Item>
    <Item>1056 589 50 50</Item>
    <Item>1031 722 50 50</Item>
    <Item>981 867 50 50</Item>
    <Item>824 854 50 50</Item>
    <Item>641 747 50 50</Item>
    <Item>774 639 50 50</Item>
    <Item>641 566 50 50</Item>
    <Item>691 442 50 50</Item>
  </TowerBuildSpots>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

"Path" is an array of Vector2s, and "TowerBuildSpots" is an array of Rectangles

```
Public Vector2[] Path;
Public Rectangle[] TowerBuildSpots;
```

I have followed other peoples code examples that i have seen for collections and have used the  tags within my Path tag, however i get the following error whenever i try to compile my code

```
Error   1   There was an error while deserializing intermediate XML. 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 6, position 6.
```

This line is the first  in the file.

Could anyone please add any insight into this issue please? It would be of great help. Thank you!

Alasdair

edit: My deserialize code is here:

```
    public static LevelInfo Load(LevelXMLData data, ContentManager content)
    {
        int levelID = data.LevelID;

        string levelLocation = "Levels\\Level" + levelID + "\\";

        Waypoint[] path = new Waypoint[data.Path.Count()];
        WaveOfEnemies[] waves = new WaveOfEnemies[data.WaveIDs.Count()];

        TextureManager[] images = LevelImageInfo.Load(content.Load<LevelImageXMLData[]>(levelLocation + "ImageData"), content);

        // load waypoints
        for (int i = 0; i <= data.Path.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            path[i] = new Waypoint(data.Path[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= data.WaveIDs.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            waves[i] = LoadWave(content.Load<WaveXMLData>(levelLocation + "Waves\\" + data.WaveIDs[i]));
        }

        return new LevelInfo(levelID, images, path, waves, data.WaveInterval, data.TowerBuildSpots);
    }
```

and my LevelXMLData struct is here:

```
public struct LevelXMLData
{
    [ContentSerializer]
    public int LevelID;
    [ContentSerializer]
    public Vector2[] Path; 
    [ContentSerializer]
    public string[] WaveIDs;
    [ContentSerializer]
    public int WaveInterval;
    [ContentSerializer]
    public Rectangle[] TowerBuildSpots;
}
```

Comment: You don't show your deserialize code.

Comment: I just use the content pipeline to load the XML file. - edited original post

Comment: Okay, i found my problem eventually. I just needed to remove <Item></Item> from each element in my vector2[] and rectangle[].